# Visual Studio 2017 Community Version Build Project Not Responding

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I have installed VS 2017 Community version today. I opened VB.Net web project which was written in 2010.

I migrated project successfully. But When I am building project VS 2017. It  becomes unresponsive.

I have tried many solutions suggested on internet but no success.

1. Running VS 2017 as Administrator not working.
2. Minimize the parallel processes from 8 to 1 in Build & Run Configuration with minimum verbosity.
3. Clean all old local cache from App Data.

Still not able to build my project. Any early help will be highly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: So does VS simply hang when compiling your project ? Does it do the same with a new VB.net web project ?

Comment: @auburg yes it is doing in both cases. Be it new project or old.

Comment: What about other new project types (i.e. Winforms , Console / C# apps etc) ?

Comment: I found even one of the dramatic experience. I went ahead and select default browser even then it became non responsive.

Comment: [report this as feedback to Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-report-a-problem-with-visual-studio-2017?view=vs-2017)

Comment: Yes I did but is not going to solve my problem in near term. I am still figuring out to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is resolved. It was installation issue and some background optimization services by default stopped all the time.

I have uninstalled the VS 2017 and re-installed it.

PS: I need to remove all the registry values for VS 2017 manually to clean up the installation.